# ggplot y labels missing on windows

Tags: r, ggplot2

In running a `knitr` report I noticed that `ggplot2` produces a graph without y-ticks/labels on *Windows*, but does on my *Linux/Rstudio* install.

The following codes shows the issue for me.

```
df=data.frame(pos=seq(1,10),data=seq(10,1,-1))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=pos,y=data))+ 
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=seq(1,10,2))+ 
  geom_line()
```

Here are the graphs that I get:

> **Windows**
>   [image: Windows]
>
> **Linux**
>   [image: RStudio/Linux]

The breaks show if I remove the `scale_y_discrete` function call, however I need it for formatting my output.

Is this an environmental issue?  A configuration issue?

Comment: It's not quite clear why you use `scale_y_discrete` when you have a _continuous_ `y`.

Comment: Just my lack of awareness,  using `scale_y_continuous` instead does make the issue go away. Thanks